# Custom IPv6 stateless autoconfiguration suffix

Tags: linux, ipv6, ip-address

When a router announces an IPv6 prefix via [Router Advertisements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbor_Discovery_Protocol), a host can use [SLAAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address#Stateless_address_autoconfiguration) to automatically derive the remaining bits from its MAC and use the combination as its globally routable IPv6 address.

As far as I understand, all this is magically done by the kernel. This behaviour can also be altered by setting `net.ipv6.conf.<interface>.use_tempaddr = 1`, which will make the host generate a random suffix instead of deriving one from its MAC.

The question is whether there is a way to make the host use a predefined *fixed* suffix for this purpose. Is there a way to tell the kernel to do that? If no, then what are other options? Is there something like a daemon that listens for advertisements and runs a custom hook (which will configure the ip address)?